# HTML5 disable default controls

Tags: html, video, controls

I would like to know how do I disable the Showcontrols options for HTML5 video.

This is what I want to disable:

The reason I want to disable is that If I use my custom controls and If I mouse hover I need to show my custom controls and when I leave the mouse it should hide the controls and the problem is that when I select the ShowControls the default controls is showing up which I dont want.

Can anyone suggest me how do I procees with that?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var video = document.getElementById("video"); // assuming "video" is your videos' id
video.removeAttribute("controls");
```

for example: http://jsfiddle.net/dySyv/1/

Comment: +1. Just to make it clear: do not set the **controls** attribute, see http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#attr-media-controls

Comment: @Martin-Thanks for the quick reply.And this is exactly what I need! :)

Comment: I tried this code locally, it worked at first, but as soon as I replaced `src="/movie.mp4"` with a path to an actual video, the `Show Controls` option is always there when you right click the video. E.g. https://jsfiddle.net/dySyv/136/

Comment: I think that the `Show Controls` option should always be available to the user when they right-click the video. The original question that I answered was how to programmatically hide the controls. The question, as far as I understood it, was not to prevent `Show Controls` from appearing when the user right-clicked on the video.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myVideo = document.getElementById("video"); 

function playPause() { 
    if (myVideo.paused) 
        myVideo.play(); 
    else 
        myVideo.pause(); 
}
```

```html
<body>
<video id="video" oncontextmenu="return false;" >
   <source src="https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/track/basics/treeOfLife/video/developerStories-en.webm" />
</video>
<br>
 <button onclick="playPause()">Play/Pause</button> 
 </body>
```

Video controles are hidden here and for not to turn on it by user I added `oncontextmenu="return false;"`.Context menu for video is not shown now.so user cannot turn on it.

(You can add custom context menu and also create custom controls for *play/pause*,*seeking*,to *show time* and also to *change volume* using javascript.)

Hope it helps...:)