# How to host a video on a website while controlling the view count/view manner per user?

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, html5-video

I am building a website where I want to display a video to my users, and make sure that the user can only watch it one time without any control over the video. I want to show the video to the user later after the user goes through some process, that second time the user should have control over the video. This means that:

1. Controls should be disabled (the user can't pause, rewind, forward, etc..)
2. It should not be possible to see the video again by refreshing the page
3. The user should not be able to download the video to watch it again.
4. The controls should be enabled again only after a sequence of steps are made by the user (e.g. clicking a button)

As for 1, I tried setting the controls attribute in html5's `<video>` element to `false` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854252/html5-disable-default-controls). But when you refer to an actual video the user can then be able to right click and show controls (e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/dySyv/136/).

I think I'll handle 2 using JS flags or backend sessions, as long as I can have access to event listeners (e.g. `video.onended`).

3 is not possible using html5, 4 is possible but I can't hide the controls in the first place..

How do I do that? or should I use a third-party library?

Comment: I think there's no conventional way how to prevent user from downloading HTML5 video (you provide the link to the source and any user can then download it -- any user means really experienced user, but that doesn't solve the problem) ___ You can disable right click on the video element (but it's still bypassable using console) ___ You can set timer for the video duration when the video starts and than end it --> but all this stands and falls on javascript (when disabled, user can "hard-download" it) ___ eg. all Youtube videos are downloadable even though copyrighted :)

Comment: There's actually solution to the problem which is used by Google Play Movies, Netflix, etc. and that's implementing CDM (content decryption module) which is way beyond my knowledge. Also many internet VODs still use Silverlight to protect the sources... so I think you'll have to work just with some javascript tricks to prevent as many users as possible from downloading it (but still knowing it's bypassable) :/