# How to disable the download button in chrome

Tags: html, css, video, html5-video, disabled-control

I have used this video Player for my application and the videos are coming properly but the download button is coming in chrome and Firefox it is not coming.
So i want to Disable the video button in chrome how can i do that..?

And one more thing i don't want to allow the right click option on the video how can i do that help is appreciated.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Open this link in chrome and firefox

[image]

Comment: More here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854252/html5-disable-default-controls

Comment: my question is different @mplungjan i want to disable only download button icon not everything like controls.. nbetter you remove that duplicate tag

Comment: So this is a better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41115801/in-chrome-55-prevent-showing-download-button-for-html-5-video

Comment: Which is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39602852/disable-download-button-for-google-chrome/40975859#40975859

Comment: First you understand the question man why you are so hurry to make it duplicate i have searched stack-flow everywhere but related solution is not there

Comment: If the two duplicates do not work for you TELL us. Show effort and code. The two last duplicates I posted are asking the EXACT same question as you are and the answers seem to work - did you try any of them - and if you did why are you not letting us know you did so we are not wasting our time ? I am not the only one who would hammer close your question which is missing a [mcve]

Comment: You do realise that "It cannot be reliably done" is also a valid answer? There is even a bug report as described here: https://cmsdk.com/css3/in-chrome-55-prevent-showing-download-button-for-html-5-video.html